# Select text in Bokeh plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh

I would like to be able to search for specific words in my Bokeh plot. Say that I have a very simple plot:

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file

x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save,box_select"

p1 = figure(title="Some sample title", tools=TOOLS)
p1.circle(x,y, legend="sin(x)")

output_file("legend.html", title="legend.py example")
show(p1)
```

Which results in

[image]

I would like to be able to search the text in my browser using [ctrl+f] or [cmd+f]. Is there any way to do that? I would like to be able to search for the title and/or for labels, so in this case, example queries would be one of {sample, title,1,0.5}. Of course this example is hypothetical, but I think it's enough to illustrate the question.

Is there any way to use browser search functionality inside a Bokeh plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this in Boken currently, as it renders to an HTML5 canvas object, so the browser just sees the final result of the rendering. If you're willing to use Bokeh's sister library HoloViews, it however has a both Bokeh and SVG backend. When rendered through that SVG backend, your browser will then have access to all the text elements.

To help evaluate plotting libraries to see if they're suitable for your purpose, what you're looking for is basically a SVG backend. Usually it's easy to find a list of supported backends in the documentation of each library.

Also note that "having all individual plot elements accessible to the browser" and "plotting a lot of data points" are conflicting goals. The HTML5 canvas backend works well for plotting lots of data (even more so with datashader) partly *because* it only exposes the final plot image to the browser. If you want to expose the details of your plot to the browser (e.g via the SVG backend), you should expect to see a performance hit at some point if your plots get bigger (more data) or otherwise more complex, compared to the HTML5 canvas backend.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you can also render Bokeh directly to SVG in browsers by setting `output_backend`. But this is a young feature and there are known issues, especially in conjunction with other interactive features. Additionally SVG performance my become unsatisfactory as smaller data sizes than the canvas backend.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this. Bokeh plots are not textual DOM elements, everything is rendered on an HTML raster canvas, which the browser only sees as an rectangular area of RGBA pixels.